# Make regex find a text inside tags with line breaks in the content - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

thanks for coming here, so i've got this little code:

```
while(/\[del\](.*?)\[\/del\]/i.exec(text) != null)
text = text.replace(/\[del\](.*?)\[\/del\]/i, "<s>$1</s>");
```

but when there are line breaks, it wont match.
Example:

> [del]asdsadasda
> asdadsadsadsadasdsadsa[/del] - this won't be matched

I'm really new to regex, so what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: replace the dot with `[\s\S]`. The "while" statement is totally useless, you can remove it.

Comment: And without the "while" it won't replace the other matches(if there are more)

Comment: Off-topic: It seems your are replacing bbcode `[del]` with html `<s>`. Note there is also a [`<del>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/edits.html#the-del-element) html element, not to be confused with [`<s>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-s-element).

Comment: Oh yeah, i know that, the `<s>` was just to make the code smaller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default in many regex flavors, the dot doesn't match the newline character. Javascript doesn't have the singleline modifier `(?s)` to change this behaviour. The most current trick to match all characters including newlines is to use `[\s\S]` that matches *all that is a whitespace character and all that is not a whitespace character*.

As an aside comment, you don't need to put the `replace` method in a `while` loop, since the `replace` will only perform a replacement if something is found. If you want to replace all occurences, just add the g command at the end of the pattern.

```
text = text.replace(/\[del\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/del\]/ig, "<s>$1</s>");
```

Note that for this specific replacement, since your `del` tag doesn't seem to have parameters, you can simply write:

```
text = text.replace(/\[(\/?)del\]/ig, "<$1s>");
```

*(it avoids a lot of work)*

Comment: Thanks for the tips, they really saved my fingers!